# log4j2 slf4j logging only error

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

Only error logs are showing in console. No debug, info, warn logs are showing up. Below are the configurations. Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

I used the above depnedencies with the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
 <Appenders>
  <File name="A1" fileName="A1.log" append="false">
   <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
 </File>
 <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
 </Console>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
 <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">
  <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
 </Logger>
 <Logger name="com.mypackage" level="debug">
 <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
 <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
 </Logger>
 <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info"/>
 <Root level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
 </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I used the below code to log:

```
logger.trace("Entering application.");
logger.info("Test");
System.out.println("Hello");
logger.debug("dbg");
logger.error("dbg");
logger.warn("dbgfatal");
logger.error("dbg error");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config file should be named log4j2.xml and be located in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, name was log4j.xml, so it was not taking it.

Comment: I have a log4j2.json under my src/main/resources and it's not working...

Comment: @FearX Try switching on internal log4j logging: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

your root level should be lower : `debug`  or `trace`

```
<Root level="debug">
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root level should be "debug" and appender ref should be "Console":

```xml
<root level='debug'>
    <appender-ref ref='Console'/>
</root>`
```

Comment: <root level='debug'>
      <appender-ref ref='Console'/>
    </root>